# Obtaining the derived type from an instance of the base type when many derived types are possible

Tags: c++, templates, types

I've seen solutions to this problem that suggest using

```
if( dynamic_cast<DerviedType1*>( base ) ){
    // Do something
}
else if( dynamic_cast<DerviedType2*>( base ) ){
    // Do something else
}
else if( dynamic_cast<DerviedType3*>( base ) ){
   // Do another thing
}
// and so on
```

While functional, this solution is far from elegant, and I was hoping that there was a single-line solution, along the lines of `decltype` or `typeid`, neither of which help me here.

My specific problem is as follows. I have a function that will take a pointer to an instance of the base class as an argument. This function will then call a template function within that takes the derived type as its parameter. E.g.

```
void myFunc( Base *base )
{
    myTemplateFunc<Derived>();
}
```

I would like to keep my code simple, without a laundry list of `if` statements, but I'm not sure how to go about it. It should be noted that the `Base` object itself will not be passed into the template function, only it's type.

For reference, I'm looking for something along the lines of

```
void myFunc( Base *base )
{
    myTemplateFunc<decltype(base)>();
}
```

but this will only return the `Base` type, which doesn't help me here.

Comment: Actually `decltype(base)` will be a `Base*`, not `Base`. Also, template parameters for templates have to be known at compile time, so you'd have to make `myFunc` a template that gets called with the real type of `Base`, which may or may not be possible, so templates by themselves aren't going to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The other way is multiple dispatching

```
class Base
{
   virtual void dispatch () = 0;
};

template <class T>
class BaseTpl : public Base
{
public:
  void dispatch () {myTemplateFunc<T> ();}
};
```

and then

```
class DerviedType1 : public BaseTpl <DerviedType1>
{
};
```

and actual ussage

```
void myFunc( Base *base )
{
    base->dispatch ();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
struct Base
{
   virtual void execute() = 0;
}

struct Derived : Base
{
   virtual void execute()
   {
      myTemplateFunc<Derived>();
   }
}
```

and just call it as

```
void myFunc( Base *base )
{
    base->execute();
}
```

which will dispatch to the correct method.

Comment: I added an example with CRTP, I hope I didn't mess up your answer.

Comment: @SethCarnegie well, as I didn't think about this, I rolled-back. Perhaps you could add an answer (+1 from me if you do)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I wish I could accept more than one since they're both great. Please accept a +1 instead :)